# Put single element (float, str...) into list

Tags: python, list

I would like to write functions that work with single element or list as argument. I would prefer not to use `isinstance` to check the type of the argument. How do I put a single element into a list, and don't convert already existing list to list of list?

This function would be the equivalent of `np.asarray` for arrays.

```
def tolist(obj):    
    """
    Function made to convert float or list to list
    """

    if not isinstance(obj,list):
        if type(obj).__module__=='numpy':
            obj=list(obj)
        else:
            obj=[obj]
    return obj
```

Comment: "I'm not sure I'm doing it in the pythonic way." You haven't shown us which way you're doing it

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account.  [On topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and [... the perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) apply here.
StackOverflow is not a design, coding, research, or tutorial resource.
However, if you follow whatever resources you find on line, make an honest coding attempt, and run into a problem, you'd have a good example to post.

Comment: Please show code.

Comment: Since many tutorials on Python sequences cover this topic, I suspect you're also short on the effort we expect before posting.

Comment: Probably you should just use `isinstance`, that's the most straight forward way. You could also consider [functools.singledispatch](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.singledispatch) if this is going to be your first argument

Comment: I'd argue it's *not* Pythonic (or a good idea in *any* language) to do this at all. Write a function that deals with lists, and if the caller wants to work with a single value, they can wrap it in a list themselves. `do_for_all([3])` instead of `do_for_one_or_all(3)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use exceptions:

```
try:
    list_to_use.extend(value_to_add)
except TypeError:
    list_to_use.append(value_to_add)
```

Update: don't saw, that you also want to add strings, too; therefore, there is no good way to handle this case.

```
if isinstance(value_to_add, str):
    list_to_use.append(value_to_add)
else:
    try:
        list_to_use.extend(value_to_add)
    except TypeError:
        list_to_use.append(value_to_add)
```

Comment: Yeah there is, use `isinstance`, although, one could argue that this is fundamentally a bad design choice (a function accepting either a list or an element to go in a list) that encourages lazy programming

Comment: And then the user is confused as to why their single string argument doesn't behave the way they expect.

Comment: I'm specifically writing a package for non-python users that might forget to put brackets around a string for example, therefore I need to handle all possibilities, as good scripts should do I suppose. Thanks for the answers

Comment: @ChrisB um, no you shouldn't do this. Your function should fail early. That is what good scripts do. Bad scripts propagate subtle bugs by guessing at what the caller *meant*.

Comment: Good to know @juanpa.arrivillaga. I'll keep that in mind for my functions! Thx!